# Delegating a Reverse DNS Zone

Tags: linux, dns, centos, centos-7, bind

I am using Bind 9 under CentOS 7.

My company's domain name is **mycorp.com**.

I administer **mylab.mycorp.com**.

IT forwards (not delegates) queries for **mylab.mycorp.com** to my nameserver **ns1.mylab.mycorp.com**.

My address space is **10.0.0.0/22**, which I subnet / break into DNS zones as follows:
**10.0.0.0/24** --> Machines in this IP range lie within zone **a.mylab.mycorp.com**. My nameserver is authoritative for this zone.

**10.0.1.0/24** --> Machines in this IP range lie within zone **b.mylab.mycorp.com**. My nameserver is authoritative for this zone.

**10.0.2.0/24** --> Machines in this IP range lie within zone **c.mylab.mycorp.com**. My nameserver is authoritative for this zone.

**10.0.3.0/24** --> Machines in this IP range lie within zone **d.mylab.mycorp.com**. My nameserver is *not* authoritative for this zone.

IT also forwards (not delegates) the following to my nameserver:
**0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.** --> My nameserver is authoritative for this zone.
**1.0.10.in-addr.arpa.** --> My nameserver is authoritative for this zone.
**2.0.10.in-addr.arpa.** --> My nameserver is authoritative for this zone.
**3.0.10.in-addr.arpa.** --> My nameserver is  *not* authoritative for this zone.

I have successfully delegated zone **d.mylab.mycorp.com** to **ns1.d.mylab.mycorp.com**.

I would also like to delegate zone **3.0.10.in-addr.arpa** to **ns1.d.mylab.mycorp.com**.

To try and do so, I have created these resource records:

```
3.0.10.in-addr.arpa.   NS   ns1.d.mylab.mycorp.com  
ns1.d.mylab.mycorp.com   A   10.0.3.1 ; Glue
```

However, I also have the following option configured:

```
options {
   ...
   forwarders { 10.10.10.10; };
   ...
}
```

I am finding that queries for **3.0.10.in-addr.arpa** get forwarded to **10.10.10.10**, rather than delegated to **ns1.d.mylab.mycorp.com**.

Note that I am not authoritative for **0.10.in-addr.arpa**.

Is there a way I can delegate **3.0.10.in-addr.arpa** to **ns1.d.mylab.mycorp.com**?

Comment: Only the authority for 0.10.in-addr.arpa. can delegate 3.0.10.in.addr.arpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting wurtel's comment as an answer:

Only the authority for 0.10.in-addr.arpa. can delegate 3.0.10.in.addr.arpa. – wurtel Jul 17 at 7:25

Note: Credit due to wurtel